# Promela channel "??" removal order

Tags: model-checking, promela, spin

Can anyone explain to me the order of what happens in the following?

```
if
 :: a_channel??5 -> // do A
 :: value_1 == value_2 -> // do B
fi;
```

So basically how I understand it is that for the statement to be executable, 5 needs to be in the channel. I understand that 5 will then be removed from the channel as a result(if it is indeed in the channel). What I don't undertstand is when 5 will be removed. Will 5 be removed after the statement is executed or will it be removed before during the check for execution.

Promela ref link for receiving: http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/receive.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume `a_channel??5` is contained in the body of some process `P_i`.

> Will 5 be removed after the statement is executed or will it be removed before during the check for execution.

The *"check for execution"* is a necessary but not sufficient condition for the removal of `5` from the channel. The other, necessary, condition is that `P_i` is selected for execution and executes the statement `a_channel??5`.

---

A more detailed answer.

The statement `a_channel??5` is a statement that it is **not always executable**. It is *executable* only **when** `5` is in channel. *(**e.g.** if `5` was in the channel, but it has been removed [e.g. by someone else], `a_channel??5` is no longer executable)*

After each time a process `P_i` executes an **atomic (set of) instruction(s)**, the scheduler may decide to pre-empt it and to allow some other process `P_j` with some *executable* instruction to continue.

When a process `P_i` reaches a *non-executable* statement, it is always immediately pre-empted by the scheduler. In this case, it is an error condition if there is no other process `P_j` with some immediately *executable* instruction that can be scheduled for execution *(i.e. the famous "invalid end state" error)*.

If statement `a_channel??5` is executable and process `P_i` is selected for execution (or keeps going), then `a_channel??5` executes **atomically** and it immediately removes the *(first occurrence)* of the value `5` from the channel.

Comment: In the updated example above (assuming 5 is already in the channel), statement a_channel??5 might be atomically executed removing 5 from the channel, but does that mean it has to now do A ? Or can it still do B if value_1 == value_2 (i.e.  5 would be removed but it does B instead).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation by the way!

Comment: @Rajdeep According to the above explanation, the removal of `5` requires the **execution** of `a_channel??5`. According to the **branching** semantics, the execution of a **guard** is followed by the execution of its body `// do A`. Therefore, if process `P_i` selects the guard `a_channel??5` then it cannot execute neither `value_1 == value_2` nor `// do B`, unless the *if statement* is contained in some **loop** and next time it reaches the same branch it makes a different choice.

Comment: @Rajdeep Perhaps a simpler example than `a_channel??5` is to look at what happens when  another expression with side effects is used as a guard, like for example`x = x + 1`. Would you expect `x` to be incremented even when its branch is not taken? Of course not! As an exercise, you can use *LTL* model checking to formally verify this.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thanks alot for the explanation !!